# what is the motivation behind the procedure for multiplication method for hashing?

Tags: methods, hash, hashtable, multiplication

I started learning about hashing from CLRS (Cormen et al.). I was able to understand the mathematical procedure and how the computer implementation follows. The book simply states the mathematical procedure as-

```
-> multiply the key k with a constant A (0<A<1), results into kA;

-> extract the fractional part of kA by doing (kA mod 1);

-> multiply the result with m (usually taken to be a power of 2 for easy 
implementation on computers);

-> take the floor of this result and that is the hashed value;

-> therefore, this is the hashing function, h(k) = floor[m*(kA mod 1)]
```

the book further states how it would be implemented on most computers, it's advantages over the division method and Knuth's suggestion for value of 'A'.

What I'm not able to understand is that WHY do we follow this procedure of specifically multiplying the key with a number(A) in the range 0 to 1 and then taking the fractional part followed by multiplication by m and then taking the floor?

Does this produce hashed values that "closely resemble" SUHA(assumption of simple uniform hashing), i.e. ideally each key should independently hash to any of the m slots, so does this method produce results "closer" to this ideal?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally hashing should satisfy the assumption of simple uniform hashing.

For example in a hashing function `h(k): U--> {0...m-1}` where `U` is the universe of possible keys and `m` is the size of the table

Which means any key in the Universe of keys should be equally likely to end up in the same location each time you hash it and distribution of keys is evenly spread across all the locations right?

Well, it's not that easy in practice, we don't know the probability of the distribution of the keys in advance and even if we did we still don't know which ones gonna be drawn out of that universe.

So we need to get practical based on what we know about the keys to create some computation on `k` that performs well and distribute keys well across the table.

That's where we are getting into trading between methods,

Take the division method: Simply `h(k) = k mod m` Key modulo the size of your table.
Simple, fast and produces only legal values but you gotta have to choose your `m` very carefully! For example, if the table is a power of 2 you are essentially taking the least significant bits of `k`and those keys likely to show a certain structure. So pick a prime number for `m` probably close to an exact power of 2.

Let's move on to the multiplication method for some contrast: `h(k) = floor[m*(kA mod 1)]` where `(0<A<1)`

We are multiplying our key with a fractional number so the `mod 1` is there to take the fractional component out. Essentially you will and up with multiplying `m` with a number between 0 up to but not including 1 and finally, we are taking the floor of the result of that to get an integer.
This is slower than division method but it doesn't matter what you choose for `m` Value of `m` is not critical!

Back to your question, It entirely depends on what kind of implementation you have and therefore how you should use hash tables accordingly. There are many out there.

Answer (score 0):

When we multiply the fractional-part of `kA` (which is somewhere in interval [0,1]) by `m`, we are generating a value in range 0 to m-1, which can then be used as the hash-table's index. Let us denote the fractional-part of `kA` by `{kA}`.

This procedure too, like any other hash function, may or may not distribute the input keys (which are not known in advance) uniformly.

Suppose there are a couple of consecutive integer keys and we want to ensure their uniform distribution. For that, we will need to make the values `{kA}` as uniform as possible in interval [0,1]. If that can be done, the final hash (after multiplying with `m`) will also be distributed well in range 0 to `m-1`. In this sense, the value of `A` then becomes important, and CLRS recommends (which itself refers Knuth) `1/golden-ratio` for `A`. With this, the generated values of `{kA}` will be well-distributed in [0,1].